# Phonegap < Android 4.4 - DeviceReady not triggered

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm building a Phonegap application, and my initial tests were on a Android 4.4 version. Now when testing the application on Android < 4.4 (4.0.3 & 4.2) I notice that the deviceReady is not triggered.

On > 4.4 everything is working perfect... 
As the application is working fine on > 4.4, it's difficult to provide more technical details about the application. Since I don't know what is going on and why it's not working on previous Android versions...

Application set-up:
Phonegap / AngularJS

When debuging the application (alerts & JSConsole output) I notice that the deviceReady is not triggered.

Can anybody point me in a better way to see why? Or have any experience about this subject?

Thank you very much...

My config file with the used plugins:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.sdp.serviceApp"
    versionCode = "1"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

<name>SDP Service App</name>
<description>SDP Service App</description>
<author href="http://www.sdp.be" email="daan.desmedt@sdp.be">SDP Belgium</author>   

<icon src="res/icon/icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />

<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" /> 
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />

<access origin="*" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>

<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>

<gap:platform name="android" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.7" />

</widget>
```

Plugin list:

- com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
- org.apache.cordova.camera
- org.apache.cordova.device
- org.apache.cordova.file
- org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
- org.apache.cordova.geolocation
- org.apache.cordova.network-information
- uk.co.whiteoctober.cordova.appversion

Comment: I ran into an issue where device ready was _kinda_ firing.  This may or may not be your issue, so this link may help.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9256.

Comment: Cordova supports Android 4.0.x, see here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/platforms/android/index.html. So, I think there is a problem with one of the plugins. I would start by disabling the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help if:

- you are on a cdvfile:// url
- Using a lower Android OS, like 4.4

You can try updating/adding the cordova-plugin-file to a certain commit I have made to fix this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/miloproductionsinc/cordova-plugin-file.git#6e9fe5c6930cbd457be4ddcbec9666fc98e05257
```

When the related pull request goes through I will link to the official repository.

Here is the [issue detailing the problem](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/329)